# How to scale a pie-chart and bar-chart to both display

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [2,3,4,5,6]
z = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6]
a = [10, 12, 14, 3]
b = [1, 2, 3,4]
c = [1,2,3,4,5]


scatter = plt.scatter(x,y,marker="o", label="Label 1",color="r")
line = plt.plot(x,z,label="Label 2",color="g")
bar = plt.bar(a,b)
pie = plt.pie(c,labels=["Tom", "Dick", "Harry", "And", "Nervous"])
plt.title("Scatter and line")
plt.xlabel("X-label")
plt.ylabel("Y-label")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The above code prints everything that I want however the pie chart does not align with the graphed data. Is there any way to have MatPlotLib either open them as two separate side-by-side charts or have them overlay the pie chart over the bar chart at a specified position (e.g: x=15,y=15)

I've included a sample below (the legends are a bit off, so ignore them)
I want an output either like the top row OR the second row.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You have four plot commands  in your code. Please include a sample of your desired figure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that [matplotlib.pyplot.subplot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html) can plot them side by side.

I rearranged your code a little bit to fit these two subplots:

```py
# create first subplot on the left (1 row, 2 columns, position 1)
plt.subplot(121)
pie = plt.pie(c,labels=["Tom", "Dick", "Harry", "And", "Nervous"])

# create second subplot on the right (1 row, 2 columns, position 2)
plt.subplot(122)
scatter = plt.scatter(x,y,marker="o", label="Label 1",color="r")
line = plt.plot(x,z,label="Label 2",color="g")
bar = plt.bar(a,b)
plt.title("Scatter and line")
plt.xlabel("X-label")
plt.ylabel("Y-label")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image: result]